# Does "dedicated" imply "dedicated to something/someone"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, expressions

When I say something like "John is a dedicated person", does it only make sense if there is a specific cause or person that John is dedicated to, or can we say it in the same manner as "John is a brave person" (that is, having the word "dedicated" describe a general trait of the person, independent of any specific cause)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/dedicated) defines it as **Devoted to a task or purpose.** It gives the example ‘*a team of dedicated doctors*.’

So no, it's not a general trait of the person.